# Nivo ResponsiveLine data different thatn tooltip values

Tags: reactjs, nivo-react

I have two Arrays with x and y values.
data - has a percentage associated with each month {'x': month, 'y': percent} ...
dataTotals - has a frequency value associated with each month {'x': month, 'y': freq} ...
I want to use data to plot the graph and I've been able to do this successfully so far.
What I would like is to have the corresponding freq value for each month shown in the tooltip. Right now I'm only able to get the percentage values in the tooltip

.
.
.

```
<ResponsiveLine
  data={data}
  sliceTooltip={({ slice }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {slice.points[0].data.yStacked}
      </div>
    );}}
```

.
.
.
This works correctly to get percentage values in the tooltip. However, I'm unsure how to get the dataTotals value 'slice by slice'